# Display file metadata like owner and group using Rust

Tags: linux, rust

I'm working recursive file search and got it to work with simple permissions, but I can't determinate how to get the owner (owner id) or the group (group id) of an folder or file. I've discovered how to get the current permissions of an file or folder. I get an uint_32 so about 9 bits of this are used to save the permission. But where and how are the timestamp is saved? and the owner? On my research I've read that the linux kernel allowing more than 4 billion users on an system. Obviously this isn't in the uint_32 that I'm getting.

I'm working in rust and would not fear to write a C module.
But now here is my main.rs:

```
use std::fs::*;
use std::os::unix::fs::MetadataExt;
use std::os::unix::fs::PermissionsExt;
use std::mem::transmute;


fn main(){
    let meta = metadata("./test.txt");
    if meta.is_ok(){
        let m:u32 = meta.unwrap().permissions().mode();
        //let bytes: [u8; 4] = unsafe { transmute(m.to_be()) };//etv. used later

        print!("{}",if (m & (0x1<<9)) >= 1 {"d"}else{"-"});
        print!("{}",if (m & (0x1<<8)) >= 1 {"r"}else{"-"});
        print!("{}",if (m & (0x1<<7)) >= 1 {"w"}else{"-"});
        print!("{}",if (m & (0x1<<6)) >= 1 {"x"}else{"-"});
        print!("{}",if (m & (0x1<<5)) >= 1 {"r"}else{"-"});
        print!("{}",if (m & (0x1<<4)) >= 1 {"w"}else{"-"});
        print!("{}",if (m & (0x1<<3)) >= 1 {"x"}else{"-"});
        print!("{}",if (m & (0x1<<2)) >= 1 {"r"}else{"-"});
        print!("{}",if (m & (0x1<<1)) >= 1 {"w"}else{"-"});
        println!("{}",if (m & 0x1) >= 1 {"x"}else{"-"});
        println!("{:b}",m);
    }
}
```

Do not hesitate to modify my code if you think so.

I'm doing this for fun and to learn more about the code underneath the horizon.

Comment: *File mode* is a dozen or so bits that say what can be done with the file. These bits do not contain the uid, the gid, and a host of other information There are other parts of metadata besides the mode. Try `let user_id = meta.uid();` or something.

Comment: ty , for this quick response. your hint gave me a push in the ( i think ) right direction, ill update the post with additional code later. hopefully i can poste a full version for anyone who searchs for similar problems

Comment: Sorry I didn't see it was rust initially (was browsing from the phone), thought it was python or something. Info updated.

Comment: metedata has created,modified,accessed fields in it which returns SystemTime. You may want to check. [Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.Metadata.html#method.modified)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::os::linux::fs::MetadataExt` (or os::unix) provides relevant platform-specific functions. [Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/os/linux/fs/trait.MetadataExt.html). Looks like you need `meta.st_uid()`, `meta.st_gid()`, etc. By the way, it is much better to write your code like this:

```rust
if let Ok(meta) = metadata("./test.txt") {
  println!("{}", meta.st_gid());
  // ...
}
```

> I'm working in rust and would not fear to write a C module

Rust has excellent FFI for such cases. For example, you can add [libc](https://crates.io/crates/libc) crate with libc bindings and just call `libc::stat` function with familiar API.

Answer (score 2):

Owner is `meta.unwrap().`[`uid()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/fs/trait.MetadataExt.html#tymethod.uid) and group is `meta.unwrap().`[`gid()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/fs/trait.MetadataExt.html#tymethod.gid). They are `u32` each, which is what Linux uses.

To get the actual names, use [libc::getpwuid_r](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.48/libc/fn.getpwuid_r.html) and [libc::getgrgid_r](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.48/libc/fn.getgrgid_r.html). See also [getpwuid(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwuid) and [getgrgid(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getgrgid).